# Что такое XOR?

Tags: delphi

Никогда не понимал и не получается понять, что такое XOR. Объясните пожалуйста простыми словами и если можно, с примерами.
С уважением

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Логическая операция "исключающее или".

- FALSE **XOR** FALSE = FALSE
- FALSE **XOR** TRUE =TRUE
- TRUE **XOR** FALSE =TRUE
- TRUE **XOR** TRUE =FALSE

Операция дает FALSE если операнды равны не зависимо от них. Еще одно название "Сложение по модулю 2"

- [Сложение по модулю 2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сложение_по_модулю_2)
- [Битовые операции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Битовые_операции)

Answer (score 0):

1100

1010

--

0110